# Have I forgotten the basics?

Tags: python

Why does this not work?

```
create = input("Do you want to create the file (y/n): ")

while create != 'y' or create != 'n':
    print("\nError: " + create + " is not a valid option. Try again.\n")
    create = input("Do you want to create the file (y/n): ")
```

Comment: `while create != 'y' and create != 'n':`

Comment: Not **`or`** but **`and`**

Comment: Doesn't work either

Comment: @whonnock what version of python?

Comment: "Does not work" is not a problem statement.

Comment: I got it boys. Python was going crazy. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
create = input("Do you want to create the file (y/n): ")

while create not in ("y", "n"):
    print("\nError: " + create + " is not a valid option. Try again.\n")
    create = input("Do you want to create the file (y/n): ")
```

Comment: are you entering 'Y' and 'N' uppercase maybe? If you want case insensitivity use `while create.lower()` instead

Comment: Nevermind my interpreter session was going crazy now it works

Comment: Next alternative solution: `while create.lower() not in 'yn':`

Comment: @Matthias Nice but it would allow for "yn"

Comment: Damn. `OutOfCoffeeError` on my side.

Comment: lmao I'm about to raise that too, which will also be the direct cause of `MissingRequiredBrain`

Answer (score 0):

A slightly modified version:

```
while True:
    create = input("Do you want to create the file (y/n): ")
    if create == 'y' or create == 'n':
        break
    print(f"\nError: {create} is not a valid option. Try again.\n")
```

A more compact solution (python >= 3.8)

```
while create := input("Do you want to create the file (y/n): ") not in ['y', 'n']:
    print(f"\nError: {create} is not a valid option. Try again.\n")
```

Comment: @whonnock, can you try this?